# Apache sites are sharing the same index.html but are correctly rooted

Tags: django, apache, nginx

Reverse proxy using nginx as front-end and apache as back-end both apache sites are sharing the same index.html but are correctly rooted? any help?

- Domain1 is a django app using wsgi
- Domain2 uses node.js - is a sub-domain of domain1 and doesn`t link
  back to apache
- Domain3 is going to be the same as domain1 - a subdomain of a site i
  want to    rebuild (testing)

Domain1 and Domain3 both loading from their set roots but for something there are sharing the same index.html.

Anyone able to help me out here?

Here are my config`s for nginx/conf.d/virtual.conf and httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/virtual.conf

server {

    listen      80;
    server_name domain1.com;
    root /var/www/html/domain1.com/public_html;
    return 301 https://domain1.com;

         location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
              }
}

server {
        listen   443 ssl;
        root /var/www/html/domain1.com/public_html;
        server_name domain1.com;

        ssl                  on;
        ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/domain1.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/private/domain1.com.key;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;
        ssl_protocols  SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+EXP;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8080;
         }

         location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name domain2.com;
    root /var/www/html/domain2.com/public_html;
    return 301 https://domain2.com;

         location ~ /\.ht {
               deny all;
                 }
}

server {
        listen   443 ssl;
        root /var/www/html/domain2.com/public_html;
        server_name domain2.com;

        ssl                  on;
        ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/domain2.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/private/domain2.com.key;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;
        ssl_protocols  SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+EXP;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name domain3.com;
    root /var/www/html/domain3.com/public_html;
    return 301 https://domain3.com;

         location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}

server {
        listen   443 ssl;

        root /var/www/html/domain3.com/public_html;

        server_name domain3.com;
        ssl                  on;
        ssl_certificate      /etc/pki/tls/certs/domain3.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/pki/tls/private/domain3.com.key;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;
        ssl_protocols  SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+EXP;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8080;
         }

         location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

}

sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf 
#Listen 127.0.0.1:8080

 NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain1.com/public_html/
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/domain1.com/public_html/dir/dir/wsgi.py
  WSGIDaemonProcess rambler.io python-path=/var/www/html/domain1.com/public_html/env/lib/pyth$
  WSGIProcessGroup domain1.com
  <Directory "/var/www/html/domain1.com/public_html/dir/dir">
  <IfVersion < 2.3 >
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
  </IfVersion>
  <IfVersion >= 2.3>
   Require all granted
  </IfVersion>
  </Directory>
  ServerAlias domain1.com
  ServerName domain1.com
  ServerAdmin admin@domain1.com
  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/domain1.com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/domain1.com.key
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain3.com/public_html/
  <Directory "/var/www/html/domain3.com/public_html"> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride All 
    Order allow,deny 
    Allow from all 
  </Directory> 
  ServerName domain3.com
  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/domain3.com.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/domain3.com.key
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule security2_module>    
Include crs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf   
Include crs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/base_rules/*.conf
</IfModule>

sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
```